# "flutter build web" builds an empty index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

when I try to run `flutter create web` to make my flutter project into a web app, I open the index.html file in a web browser and the page is empty. Do you have any idea why? Here is the contents of the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="./">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="boop">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>boop</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = "4031280537";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="/flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In previous posts, the href has been the problem, but after changing it multiple times I've grown to think that that solution won't work here. flutter doctor does not report any problems either. Other href paths I have tried include: "/", "/build/", "/web/", and "/build/web/".

Comment: What makes you think that's a problem? It's going to load the compiled js and that's going to build the UI.

Comment: I must have miscommunicated. The problem is that when I open my index.html file in a browser nothing is shown except a blank screen. @RichardHeap

Comment: Have you actually tried .... reading? The file you included above literally includes the text `The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for it to work correctly`.  Your path does not start with a slash.

Comment: @JK. When I use the path "/" the same thing happens, but the icon doesn't load. I figured I would use the path "./" since the icon at least shows that way. Other paths like "/build/" or "/build/web/" yield the same results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to fix this problem, I had to host the website with Firebase and turn tree shaking off. Doing both of these things was able to fix the problem for me.